# How do I exit listbox in Total Commander

Tags: total-commander

I love that I can feed all the search results in Total Commander to listbox. This means that the files appear in the previously selected file window and I can perform various operations on all of them at the same time.

However, getting back to the previously selected directory is always difficult. By trial and error, I found that I have to select a different disk drive and then go back to the directory. If I simply switch to another tab and then back, the results are still there, which is pretty annoying as I very often use tab switching to return to a favourite directory.

**Is there a proper way to exit the listbox?**

Answer (score 5):

Any of the following will perform the *Go Back* action in a Total Commander listbox:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>
2. Select the *Go Back* item in the *Commands* menu.
3. Press the <kbd>Browser Back</kbd> on a multimedia keyboard.
4. Press the <kbd>Broswer Back</kbd> on the mouse.

NOTE: To get back to exactly where you were before the search, perform a *Go Forward* action.  It is not in the menu.  Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>, the <kbd>Browser Forward</kbd> key, or <kbd>Browser Forward</kbd> mouse button.

Comment: Any option which does not change the directory from which I came? Because these commands get me either one level higher in the directory structure or to some completely different place if I switched disks before searching.

Comment: @JohnEye Try a *Go Forward* action after the *Go Back* action.  See edited NOTE in answer for details.

Comment: I know this trick, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without this side effect.